# how to create table format graph in chartjs

Tags: chart.js

I m new to chartjs and search a lot and failed to find to create graphs like provide image below

[image]

can anyone suggest to me how I can do that?

Comment: That's not really a graph, but you may get some help from this example from the chartJS site: https://www.chartjs.org/docs/next/samples/bar/floating.html

Comment: @neophytte is any other plugin I can use to achieve the above??

Comment: your use case looks more like a scheduler than a graph; you may try using Google to search for something along those lines - this might be a starting point for you: https://www.sliderrevolution.com/resources/html-calendar/ good luck finding the right tool!